# How to separate string by space in any situation?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like this:

```
SteelSeriesEngine SteelSeries.SteelSeriesEngine 2.9.2015.1 3.20.0 source
```

In general, this text is placed in 5 columns (separated by space), i can use **Regex** or **Split** to separate it:

```
var line = Regex.Split(text, @"\s+").Where(s => s != string.Empty);
  // Result:
   SteelSeriesEngine
   SteelSeries.SteelSeriesEngine
   2.9.2015.1
   3.20.0
   source
```

Now if our text is like the following

```
Steel Series Engine SteelSeries SteelSeriesEngine 2.9.2015.1 3.20.0
```

The result will be as follows:

```
Steel
Series
Engine
SteelSeries
SteelSeriesEngine 
2.9.2015.1
3.20.0
```

But the result I expect should be as follows:

```
Steel Series Engine
SteelSeries SteelSeriesEngine
2.9.2015.1
3.20.0
```

(Columns 5 or 4 may not be present) so, How can I separate these 5 columns in any situation?

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: sooooo you want your code to split at _some_ spaces, but not at _other_ spaces that are completely equal? i don't think that's possible. unless it's defined that it's always the _first_ items that can contain spaces, then you could just count the elements, and if they are more than five, join the first ones. but the best bet would be to fix your input format. encapsulate "spaced" strings with quotes, or use CSV, which has all those questions already solved.

Comment: It is really not clear what you would expect. The "any situation" rules out most solutions, like what if there are no spaces? I would suggest clarifying your actual requirements and expectations.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i cant change my input format becuase i get this from cmd output, I think it might be possible if the separation operation is done from the end

Comment: @JonasH i mean i want to get expected result (in my question)

Comment: So you want (any input) -> [magic] -> (expected result)? You need to put some constraints on what input you would accept. And from looking at your example, you need to define some rules about what should be grouped and what should be separated. Why is it `steel series engine` and `SteelSeries SteelSeriesEngine` instead of `steel series` and `engine SteelSeries SteelSeriesEngine` ?

Comment: well, you've got a possible solution in my comment. but if your output can be something like `SteelSeriesEngine SteelSeries Steel Series Engine 2.9.2015.1 3.20.0`, then you're out of luck. then your only options are a) fixing the input or b) blindly guessing and hoping for the best. although you might want to inspect your input more thoroughly - could be your columns are not actually separated by spaces, but by tabs. which changes the whole situation.

Comment: @JonasH please see my question, i updated it. i want to get all Ids , Versions and Availables separately in a list

Comment: now, with your updated data, it's a _completely_ different situation. that's why [asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is important. that's basically solved already. hint 1: _count the characters until the second column_, hint 2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0